# tampermonkey script unable to change css

Tags: css, gmail, tampermonkey

I get emails from a business associate of mine, and with my gmail page zoomed to 125% in Chrome, the right (maybe 5%) gets cut off. I went into inspect and saw that if I changed a style attribute, 'table-layout' either from 'fixed' to 'auto', or simply unchecked it (in inspect), the problem goes away.  So I wrote my first tampermonkey script to try and fix the situation, as follows:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove table-layout fixed
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  table-layout: fixed to auto, in emails
// @author       DJ
// @match        https://mail.google.com/mail
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(".ii.gt.adP.adO").children().children().children().css("table-layout", "auto");
```

I used the class names .ii.gt.adP.adO because they are in the div closest to the table in question that also seem to be stable for all emails (i.e., those class names are in multiple emails, other class names in the structure change.). The table in question is a great-grandchild of the div with those class names (hence the .children().children().children() ).  I checked that that syntax would work for a great-grandchild table [here](https://jsfiddle.net/y33on71p/3/).

Here's the pertinent section in inspector:
[image: screenshot of chrome inspector]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I changed the match statement to
    *://mail.google.com/*
per [this site](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: `waitForKeyElements()` or `MutationObserver`.  And be alert for iFrames.  This Q is probably a dupe, but my internet's slow...

Comment: @BrockAdams Not sure where you're pointing, can you elaborate?

Comment: Type the term in the SO search bar, above, and read the highest voted Q's.  I'm on dialup and don't have the patience for much more right now.

Comment: @BrockAdams Ok, will do, thanks.

Comment: @BrockAdams That did it!  Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

This is the script that worked:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove table-layout fixed
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Adam's emails contain some css, table-layout: fixed;, that's screwing up the display
// @author       DJ
// @match        *://mail.google.com/*
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle    

// ==/UserScript==
function adjustTable (jNode) {
    jNode.children().children().children().css("table-layout","auto");
}
waitForKeyElements (".ii.gt.adP.adO", adjustTable);
```

Thanks again to Brock and his utility.